# How to Shrink a VirtualBox Virtual Machine and Free Up Disk Space in nixos guest system?

Tags: virtualbox, nixos, grub

I was following this [instruction](https://www.howtogeek.com/312883/how-to-shrink-a-virtualbox-virtual-machine-and-free-up-disk-space/) to try to shrink my virtual nixos.
It says,

> You can’t actually use zerofree on your / partition while you’re booted into the standard Linux environment. Instead, you’ll want to boot into a special recovery mode where your normal root partition isn’t mounted.

But I can't find a place to boot into recovery mode in nixos.
Question: How to boot into some mode where my root partiion isn't mounted in nixos? Or how do I do zerofree in nixos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NixOS does not have a recovery mode that uses an alternative root filesystem. You can do it yourself by adding extra entries to your bootloader by adding [boot.loader.grub.extraEntries](https://nixos.org/nixos/options.html#boot.loader.grub.extraentries) to your `configuration.nix`.
This way, you can boot into an another partition. You will need to prepare an extra installation on that partition. But considering that it's a VM there's probably a better option:

You may be able to attach the root filesystem of your stopped VM to a VM that has its own rootfs with zerofree on it. This way, you won't have to muck about with extra partitions.

Comment: With the understanding, I found [SystemRescueCd Live Image](https://snippets.khromov.se/shrinking-a-virtualbox-linux-image-with-zerofree/) is also a nice solution. It use SystemRescueCd Live Image to open a root terminal and zerofree. Then I don't have to make extra partitions or open another VM. Thx for your explanation!